# How to specify Python path with VS Code via SSH?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By means of Visual Studio Code, I am trying to run the code which is on a remote server connected via SSH. The code, however, throws "No module named ..."  error when importing libraries. How to specify the paths where the modules are located. The VSCode does not seem to read the paths from the PYTHONPATH on the server.